# React Native Version mismatch. Cannot generate build in Android Studio but runs properly through VS code react-native run-android

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, android-studio

When I run `react-native run-android` from VS code it runs perfectly on my android phone. But when I try to generate build from the android studio it shows me version mismatch error. I have tried every solution from the internet but none of it resolves my issue. pleas help me out. this thing happened after I **upgraded** my react native project version from **0.57.3 to 0.58.3**. I have even search in the whole project folder there is **no such 0.57.3** found in any file or any filename or folder name. what is going wrong?

> React Native Version mismatch.
>
> Javascript Version: 0.57.3
>
> ReactNative Version: 0.58.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance to get this error when you run `npm start` somewhere else in other project but didn't shut it down when you run `react-native run-android` in current project. This make your current react-native app trying to read the js bundle of other project and cause `react-native version mismatch`.

Try run `npm start` in terminal and see if it load your js bundle properly.

Comment: i did it already. even restarted my computer. i knew the port could be the problem but it did nothing. 
even it is not working in other android phones because i thought maybe my android phone must having some caching issue but that also didn't help.

Comment: Oh, you upgraded your project, so first of all add this to your AndroidManifest.xml `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`. Next, visit this site and check if you upgrade it properly [Upgrade-helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.57.3&to=0.58.3), there are some important change in version 0.58. I upgraded my project from RN0.51.0 to 0.52, 0.53, ... 0.59.9 a month a go but ignore 0.58 for some reason and didn't get this error.

Comment: Unfortunately even that didn't help. I have even updated  `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`  to  `implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.3"  {force=true}` in android/app/build.gradle. Also did this`watchman watch-del-all && react-native start --reset-cache`. Also tried by deleting node modules. but none of this disclose my problem. my whole project was working fine just to make it 64bit compatible i am doing this. by upgrading project greater than 0.58.3 my app crashes so somewhere i found 0.58.3 is **64bit compatible**. but now stuck at mismatch error

Comment: Have you try to bundle the js by yourself? `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`. This one should read your js bundle directly one you start your app. If it work at least we have a point for other solution

Comment: Well `react-native run-android` seems to be working fine in VS code terminal as i said earlier. bundle status is 100% in the nodejs terminal which open automatically and app runs successfully in any android phone. the point is in the android studio where it shows mismatch error and cannot generate build. though i will try to run this command and get back to you asap.

Comment: `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` after running this command it shows **Loading dependency graph....done** in my VS code terminal then nothing happens. still stuck at same issue in android studio mismatch error

Comment: after deleting **index.android.bundle** and then running this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` made that error gone. hence error is solved for now dont know if anything other comes up

Comment: Nice, at least now you get rid of that annoying issue :D

Answer (score 0):

after deleting **index.android.bundle** and then running this command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/` made that error gone. hence error is solved for now dont know if anything other comes up